# how to calculate the values in table view and to display in separate label

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a list of table view item. And in each cell I have the product name, qty, price. I need to calculate the each cell product qty x price. And I have to sum all the cell total. And have to display in my separate cell. How to do that.

My table view cell code will look like this  :

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartcel", for: indexPath) as! cartTableViewCell
            cell.productName.text = Addtocartdata[indexPath.row].cartproName
            cell.productQty.text = Addtocartdata[indexPath.row].cartproPrice
            cell.productAmount.text = Addtocartdata[indexPath.row].cartproPrice
            return cell;
```

I have one separate label called `totallabel`. Please give me some code explain. On how to do the calculation of each cell and to sum all the total price. And to display the total sum in my label.

I tried :

```
 var total11 : Double = 0.0
        let totalitem : Int = self.Addtocartdata.count as Int
        for item in 0...totalitem - 1 {
            let subtotal = 0.0

            total11 = subtotal +  Double(self.Addtocartdata[item].cartproPrice!)!

        }
```

But i am getting crash on for loop that :

`fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound`

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Do a for loop on `Addtocartdata` and do simple math (qty*unitPrice) and add them? I don't understand you exact issue.

Comment: i need to calculate the each table view cell qty* price. And need to sum all cell total. Thats it. No other issues

Comment: http://zappdesigntemplates.com/real-life-example-create-an-ecommerce-app-in-ios-using-swift/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the sum in `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let sum = 0.0

    for item in AddToCart {
        sum += Double(item.cartproPrice) * Double(item.cartproQty)
    }

    label.text = "\(sum)"
    return AddToCart.count
}
```

Comment: i am getting error that `Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Int' `.on this line ` sum += item.cartproPrice! * item.cartproID!`

Comment: My cartproprice, cartproqty is string. But when i change to int also i am getting same error

Comment: change it to `Double` instead of `Int`. Use this line `sum += Double(item.cartproPrice) * Double(item.cartproQty)`.

Comment: can i perform this code with the string value for both of my cartproprice,cartproqty ??

Comment: Yes you can use it for both `cartproprice` and `cartproqty`. Just change this line with the one that I have provided you and see if it works.

Comment: now my both` cartproprice and cartproqty` are as string. So its saying cant perfrom * for string.

Comment: did you convert the `Strings` to `Double` before multiplying? I have edited my answer. Have a look.