# Calculate value in each cell in tableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm am trying to get a total from each `tableView`s cell to then add to a total label. As each cell could have a different quantity as well as price I am using `Array`s for both quantity and the products *base* price.

I've followed this question/answer, but looking at it the person asking is using structs: [how to calculate the values in table view and to display in separate label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504091/how-to-calculate-the-values-in-table-view-and-to-display-in-separate-label)

```
var total = 0.0
var basePriceArray = [2.45, 18.95, 3.8]
var quantityArray = [2.0, 1.0, 5.0]
```

**cellForRowAt**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! BasketCell
let basePriceAtIndex = basePriceArray[indexPath.row]
let quantityAtIndex = quantityArray[indexPath.row]
let priceAtIndex = basePriceAtIndex * quantityAtIndex
//When I add the priceAtIndex to the cell label it is calculating perfectly
//ie 4.9, 18.95, 19

//Below is my problem
for _ in productNameArray {
    total += priceAtIndex
}
print(total)

//The total is printing
  14.700000000000001 (ignore the one)
  71.55
  128.55
```

Having figured out the logic behind it, it is multiplying the `priceAtIndex` by how many products there are in the `productNameArray` (because the `for-in` loop is counting how many products there are). Then adding the last price to the next price ie

4.9 x 3 = 14.7

18.95 x 3 = 56.85 + 14.7 = 71.55

19.00 x 3 = 57 + 56.85 + 14.7 = 128.55

I understand the logic behind it, but for some reason can't figure out the fix?

**EDIT 1**
Forgot to mention there are 3 products in my `productNameArray` hence the x 3

Answer (score 1):

> I am using Arrays for both quantity and the products base price

**Don't do that**. Use a struct containing both quantity and price and a computed property for the product

```
struct Product {

    let name : String

    // many other properties 

    var quantity : Int
    var price : Double

    var priceTotal : Double {
        return Double(quantity) * price
    }
}
```

and a data source array

```
var products = [Product]()
```

In cellForRow `map` products to `priceTotal` and sum it up

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! BasketCell

let total = products.map{$0.priceTotal}.reduce(0.0, +)
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
cell.textLabel?.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: total))
```

Of course you have to update the `Product` instances of the data source if `quantity` or `price` changes.

Comment: I'll give that a go shortly, the `Array`s I'm using are being populated through Firebase, so are declared unpopulated to be populated later. I've managed to delete my entire database by mistake so I'm waiting for Firebase to restore it and will then try the above answer and let you know - many thanks

Comment: This answer implies that the incorrect total calculation is the result of not properly structuring the data.  The OP should structure the data as suggested because that's good OO practice, but the total calculation is wrong for an unrelated reason:  it multiplies the row's total by the number of rows, rather than summing the price for each row.  This answer corrects that calculation without noting it, and furthermore repeats the OP's mistake of computing this constant value (relative to row) in every row.